# Сравнить значения вложенных объектов массива с элементами другого массива

Tags: javascript

Имеется массив типа первый массив типа:

```
const arr1 = [7, 7, 6, 7, 8, 4, 8, 6, 6, 2]
```

Затем имеется второй массив, массив объектов

```
const arr2 = [
{id: 1, type: 'book'},
{id: 2, type: 'some'},
{id: 3, type: 'cat'},
{id: 4, type: 'dog'},
{id: 5, type: 'apple'},
{id: 6, type: 'pig'},
{id: 7, type: 'pen'}
]
```

Нужно id вложенных объектов массива arr2 сравнивать с элементами массива arr1. Если найдется совпадение, то есть id будет равен первому совпавшему числу из массива arr1, то значение type вывести в консоль. Подскажите, как реализовать такой функционал?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если правильно понимаю, можно так:

```js
const arr1 = [7, 7, 6, 7, 8, 4, 8, 6, 6, 2];

const arr2 = [
  {id: 1, type: 'book'},
  {id: 2, type: 'some'},
  {id: 3, type: 'cat'},
  {id: 4, type: 'dog'},
  {id: 5, type: 'apple'},
  {id: 6, type: 'pig'},
  {id: 7, type: 'pen'}
];

for (const { id, type } of arr2) {
  if (arr1.includes(id)) console.log(type);
}
```

Если первый массив большой, экономнее будет проверять по Set:

```js
const arr1 = [7, 7, 6, 7, 8, 4, 8, 6, 6, 2];
const set = new Set(arr1);

const arr2 = [
  {id: 1, type: 'book'},
  {id: 2, type: 'some'},
  {id: 3, type: 'cat'},
  {id: 4, type: 'dog'},
  {id: 5, type: 'apple'},
  {id: 6, type: 'pig'},
  {id: 7, type: 'pen'}
];

for (const { id, type } of arr2) {
  if (set.has(id)) console.log(type);
}
```

Comment: Проблема, что includes возвращает первый попавшийся элемент в true. Мне нужно пробежаться по всему arr2. В том и дело, что Set убирает дубликаты, а они мне нужны. Какой метод вместо includes можно использовать?

Comment: Из вопроса не ясно, зачем вам пробегаться по всему массиву и зачем нужны дубликаты. Объясните, пожалуйста.

Comment: @user408096 вы же сами в вопросе написали про "первое совпавшее число"

Comment: Спасибо, мне удалось решить проблему используя два цикла forEach